# Regexp. Передача регистра заменяемой буквы

Tags: c++, c, регулярные-выражения

Имеется слово, допустим, Cinderella, где Ci - превратится в Si, если введенное слово - cinderella, то ci превратится в si.

Как в правилах передать регистр заменяемой буквы?

```
 Rules->rule = {"[Cc]i", "[Cc]e", "[Cc]k", "[Cc]"}
 Rules->replacement = {"si", "se", "", "k"}
```

Comment: Это не так просто. Проще - `Rules->rule = {"Ci", "ci", "Ce", "ce", "[Cc]k", "C", "c"}
 Rules->replacement = {"Si", "si", "Se", "se", "", "K", "k"}`. Вот в `boost::regex` можно было бы поиграть с шаблонами замены.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю воспользоваться `boost::regex`, это более мощная библиотека регулярных выражений, которая поддерживает условную замену.

Замените свои регулярные выражения следующими:

```
"(?:(C)|(c))i", "(?:(C)|(c))e", "[Cc]k", "(?:(C)|(c))",
```

И шаблоны замены на

```
"(?1Si:si)", "(?1Se:se)", "", "(?1K:k)",
```

К `regex rule(Rules->rule[i]);` добавьте приставку `boost`, а вместо `words = regex_replace(words, rule, Rules->replacement[i]);` напишите `words = boost::regex_replace(words, rule, Rules->replacement[i], boost::format_all);`. Именно `boost::format_all` позволяет использовать конструкцию типа *если-то-или* в шаблонах замены.

См. [пример работы программы](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9841fc00943c8b49):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;

struct Lexer {
    vector<string> rule;
    vector<string> replacement;
};

string Parser(string words, Lexer* Rules) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Rules->rule.size(); i++) {
        boost::regex rule(Rules->rule[i]);
        //words = regex_replace(words, rule, Rules->replacement[i]);
        words = boost::regex_replace(words, rule, Rules->replacement[i], boost::format_all);
    }
    return words;
}

void init(Lexer* Rules) {
    Rules->rule = { "(\\W[Aa]\\W)", "\\W[Aa] \\W", "\\W [Aa]\\W", "^([Aa])", "(\\W[Aa])+$",
                    "(\\W[Aa]n\\W)", "\\W[Aa]n \\W", "\\W [Aa]n\\W", "^([Aa]n)", "(\\W[Aa]n)+$",
                    "(\\W[Tt]he\\W)", "\\W[Tt]he \\W", "\\W [Tt]he\\W", "^([Tt]he)", "(\\W[Tt]he)+$",
                    "(?:(C)|(c))i", "(?:(C)|(c))e", "[Cc]k", "(?:(C)|(c))",
                    "[Ee]{2}", "[Oo]{2}", "([a-zA-Z])\\1" // замена любых одинаковых букв
    };
    Rules->replacement = { "", " ", " ", "", "", // [5] ( [A-a])+$
                           "", " ", " ", "", "",
                           "", " ", " ", "", "",
                           "(?1Si:si)", "(?1Se:se)", "", "(?1K:k)",
                           "i", "u", "$1"
    };
}

void output(string words) {
    cout << words << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Lexer* Rules = new Lexer();

    string words;
    words = "Cinderella cinderella beck and Coral"; //getline(cin, words);

    ::init(Rules);
    words = ::Parser(words, Rules);
    output(words);

    return 0;
}
```

Результат: `Sinderela sinderela be and Koral`.

**Как это работает**

Разберём один пример: `(?:(C)|(c))i` => `(?1Si:si)`. Тут `(?:(C)|(c))i` находит либо `C` (и помещает его в подмаску №1) или `c` (и помещает её в подмаску №2), а потом находит `i`. Замену читаем следующим образом: `(?1` - если подмаска №1 содержит какое-то значение, подставь `Si`, иначе (`:`) подставь `si`. Конец шаблона условной замены (`)`).